# SQL COUNT(*) with GROUP BY and a final row with the total count

Tags: sql, count, db2

I want to use `COUNT(*)` on a group and then one more row at the end to give the full count.
I have used `UNION` to run the `COUNT(*)` without `GROUP BY` in a separate sub-query to give the total count, but that approach seems inefficient. Any ways to combine both?

```
SELECT PCUST, COUNT(*) FROM PAYMENT 
WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = '2020-12-30'
GROUP BY PCUST
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL', COUNT(*) FROM PAYMENT
WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = '2020-12-30'
```

As you can see from above query, I am repeating the same condition to get the partial and total counts.
Plz suggest any way to optimize this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 supports `GROUPING SETS`.  Assuming no `PCUST` values are `NULL` and it is a string, the simplest method is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(PCUST, 'TOTAL'), COUNT(*)
FROM PAYMENT 
WHERE PAYMENT_DATE = '2020-12-30'
GROUP BY GROUPING_SETS ( (PCUST), () )
```

Comment: Not sure about DB2, but in SQL Server you can shorten that to `GROUP BY ROLLUP (PCust)`

Comment: `GROUP BY ROLLUP` would work in Db2 too. See this page for examples https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059215.html